# "Values" of divergent integrals

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, integration

Are there existing theories of integration in which $I_0 = \int_0^{\infty} dx$ and $I_1 = \int_0^{\infty} x \ dx$ are well-defined infinite elements in a non-archimedean extension of the reals?  I can think of at least two different ways to set up such a theory; in one, $I_1 = I_0^2$, and in the other, $I_1 = I_0^2/2$.  (Both are based on mollification.  In the first framework, you introduce a mollified version of $dx$, namely $e^{-\lambda x} dx$, and you look at the behavior of the mollified integral for $\lambda$ near $0^+$; in the second case, you think of the integral as the area under the graph, and you mollify in the $y$-direction as well.)  There are no problems as long as the integrand is sufficiently nice, e.g., a polynomial function.  I'm wondering if any such theories have been written down and/or been found to be useful.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of this older question:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: My answer to this question is very outdated. In my current research, the quantities have alternative representations: $I_1=\int_0^{\infty } \, dx=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx=\tau=\pi\delta(0)$ and $I_2=\int_0^{\infty} x \, dx=\int_0^\infty \frac2{x^3}dx=\frac{\tau ^2}{2}+\frac{1}{24}=\frac{\omega_+^3-\omega_-^3}6$. And, in general, $\int_0^\infty x^n dx=\frac{\left(\tau +\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+2}-\left(\tau -\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{\omega _+^{n+2}-\omega _-^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$. I am not sure whether I should make a new answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an attempt of such a theory, see http://carlossicoli.free.fr/B/Burgin_M.-Hypernumbers_and_Extrafunctions__Extending_the_Classical_Calculus-Springer(2012).pdf
(Hypernumbers and Extrafunctions: Extending the Classical Calculus, by Mark Burgin).

Link in amazon:
[http://www.amazon.com/Hypernumbers-Extrafunctions-Extending-SpringerBriefs-Mathematics/dp/1441998748](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441998748)

Answer (score 1):

As I recall from QFT class the basic idea is to set the bound of integration to be $L$ and let $L \to \infty$.

$$ \int_{-L}^L dx = 2L \quad\text{ and }\quad \int_{-L}^L x \, dx = L^2 $$

The integrals in physics are badly divergent.  The usual way is to set a parameter $\epsilon$   And there is a lot of talk about this method or that method being the canonical way of assigning a value.

Dual to these are badly oscillatory integrals.  Revolving around the idea that $\sin n x \to 0$ is [weakly convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150645/question-on-weak-convergence-example) in $L^2[-\pi, \pi]$.  And  physicist might extract this limit exists generally over $\mathbb{R}$.

---

I think there is too much attention drawn to [zeta function regularization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-cdots-frac112/)  which is *intimately*  involved with the eq $\zeta(-1) = - \frac{1}{12}$.  As you note there are careful, it's possible to illustrate two **plausible** values for the same diveergent integrals and then you are in trouble.

- Henle & Kleinberg [Infinitesimal Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486428869)
- John Bell [A Primer of Infinitesimal](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521887186)

And the warning here is they use two different types of infinesimals.  As I learned... one uses non-standard analysis, the other uses smooth infinitesimal analysis.  In particular, there's difficulty with the [mean value theorem](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/derivative-applications-ab/mean-value-theorem-ab/v/mean-value-theorem-1).

---

I have a feeling you know much more than this but I am not sure what to recommend.  Lately there is the fascinating theory of [resurgence](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/pym/courses/resurgence/).  As one might know:
$$ \log n! = \sum_{k=1}^n \log k \approx \int_1^n \log x \, dx = n \log n - n $$
However if you try to "correct" this series too much, the answer on the right hand side is horribly divegent.  And this is tied to essential singularities such as $e^{-1/z}$.

Answer (score -1):

Using [this approach][1] the values of these integrals are as follows:

$$\int_0^\infty 1\, dx = \omega_-+1/2=\tau$$

Its standard part (analog of regularization in case of series) is zero.

Here $$\omega_-=\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1$$,
the quantity of natural numbers, while $\tau$ is the quantity of all even or all odd numbers, half of the quantity of all integers.

$$\int_0^\infty \sin x\,dx=1$$

$$\int_0^\infty \cos x\,dx=0$$

The standard part of arbitrary improper integral of an analytic function can be calculated from this rule from divergent series:

$$\operatorname{st}\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=\lim_{s\to0} \operatorname{st} s\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(sk)$$

The following Mathematica code does the trick:

```
Sum[f[s x],{x,1,Infinity},Regularization->"Borel"]//FullSimplify
Limit[s %,s→0]
```

Thus,

$$\operatorname{st} \int_0^\infty e^x\, dx=-1$$

which coincides with analytic continuation, by the way.

Comment: Why the downvotes and the delete vote? Something is unclear?

Comment: I think the downvoters object to metaphorical phrases like "the quantity of all even or all odd numbers".  I hope the downvoters will phrase their objections in constructive fashion. Meanwhile, let me ask a concrete question: if the term in the RHS of the first equation has a plus-sign, why should its standard part have a minus sign?

Comment: @James Propp powers of $\omega_-$ have standard part equal to Bernoulli numbers. First power has standard part -1/2, as you can see following the link. If we add 1/2, the standard part is zero. The standard part is what corresponds to the regularization of the series (as you can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_%E2%8B%AF ). This integral is 1/2 greater than the quantity of positive integers, 1/2 less than quantity of non-negative integers and twice less than the quantity of all integers (integral over all real line would be equal to the sum of all integers).

Comment: @James Propp $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1 = \omega_-$, its standard part is -1/2, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1 = \omega_+=\omega_-+1$, its stantard part is 1/2. $\omega_-^2$ has standard part of 1/6, so $-\frac{\omega_-^2}2$ has standard part -1/12. Actually, it is the value of the regularization of this series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: I think I now see why your posts got downvoted; the page you link to as a reference is unpublished and takes over-bold steps like "Now we define that to any divergent series there corresponds a non-standard number." This forum has a low level of tolerance for speculative, non-mainstream work, and I think your post fell afoul of that. If these rough ideas were developed more rigorously and published in a reputable peer-reviewed journal, they'd probably get more respect. Email me if you want to pursue this further.

Comment: @James Propp I modified my answer to give the explicit formula for transforming an integral to a series.

Comment: @James Propp I wrote a e-mail to you. I would discuss these ideas with pleasure

Comment: @James Propp I have added the easier method of calculating the thing.

Comment: I just found out about your October updates to this question (I'm not sure why the Stack Exchange software didn't notify me sooner). You say "I wrote a e-mail to you" but I never received it. Please use my gmail address, and be sure to use the word "divergent" somewhere so I can search for it.

Comment: @James Propp done.