# Integral transformation, Laplace-like

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, terminology, integral-transforms, laplace-transform

Is the following integral transformation of $f$ known (for suitable $f$ and $s\in\mathbb{C}$)?
$$
\int_1^\infty f(t) \frac{e^{-ts}}{1-e^{-ts}}dt
$$
It resembles somewhat the Laplace transformation.

What about properties, references …?

Comment: Expand the ratio of exponentials as a geometric series in exponentials.  This is called a Lambert series.  Interchange sum and integral.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nice and simple idea.

Comment: Also looks like it will have something to do with Bernoulli polynomials.

Answer (score -2):

For what it worth, in the terms of [divergent integrals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651), your transform can be rewritten as

$$\operatorname{reg} \int_1^\infty f(t)e^{-t s \omega _-}dt$$
Looks like some kind of analog of Fourier transform, if you ask me...

Comment: fixed the typo, the previous form was of course, meaningless