# Are the shapes of the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane and a disk of infinite radius different? Or otherwise, why their areas differ by $\frac\pi{12}$?

Tags: filters, regularization, divergent-integrals

The calculation of the area of the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane depends on filtering used. I think, the most natural filtering is along the radius in polar coordinates:

$$S_{\mathbb{R}^2}=\int_0^\infty 2\pi r dr=2\pi\left(\frac{\tau^2}2+\frac1{24}\right)=\pi\tau^2+\frac\pi{12}$$

where $\tau=\int_0^\infty dx$.

The regularized value of this area is $0$.
On the other hand, the area of a disk with radius $\tau$ (equal to the length of the real semi-axis) is $S_c=\pi\tau^2$, and its regularized value is $-\frac\pi{12}$.

Thus, $S_{\mathbb{R}^2}-S_c=\frac\pi{12}$. I wonder, where this area difference comes from? Does it originate from the fact that the plane should not be considered a disk of infinite radius? Or it is some glitch of integration technique?

Comment: How on earth can it be meaningful to attach any value to this integral except $\infty$?

Comment: How do you get the integral equal to $2\pi\left(\frac{\tau^2}2+\frac1{24}\right)$?

Comment: @Wojowu the formula appears in this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/342651/142708) of OP, I got lost before arriving to it so I cannot comment further on it.

Comment: @Anixx: You ask quite a few questions about your own theory of divergent integrals, which surely very few people are qualified to answer. Is there a good reference where your theory is developed in full rigour and detail, so that it might be possible for mathematicians other than you to answer your questions?

Comment: @BenMcKay for now, I think, there is no theory because I found that the proposed approach was non-natural definition. It seems, the Levi-Civita type of construction is more natural. On the other hand, I am looking at whether one can be merged/embedded into the other. If you want an outdated text, I can provide a reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the discrepancy comes from my use of non-natural definition of multiplication of divergent integrals. When using a more natural and intuitive [Levi-Civita field kind of construction](https://mathoverflow.net/q/413873/10059), the multiplication gives

$\int_0^\infty dx\cdot \int_0^\infty dx=\omega^2=2\int_0^\infty x dx$.

So, the areas in both cases are $\pi\omega^2$, where $\omega=\int_0^\infty dx$.