# What intuitive meaning "determinant" of a divergency (divergent integral, series, germ, pole or a singularity) can have?

Tags: intuition, big-picture, divergent-series, regularization, divergent-integrals

I am [working](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651) on the algebra of "divergencies", that is, infinite integrals, series, and germs.
So, I decided to construct something similar to the modulus or determinant of a matrix of these entities.

$$\det w=\exp(\operatorname{reg }\ln w)$$

which is analogous to how the determinant of a matrix can be expressed, except we take finite part (regularize) instead of taking trace.

Practically, the above calculation goes as follows:

$$\det f(\omega_-)=\exp \left( S[\ln f(x)]\right)|_{x=0}$$

where operator $S[f]=\frac{D}{e^D-1}=\Delta^{-1}D$ and for $\omega_-$ see the table below.

It does not follow the requirements for a norm (Pythagorean theorem) and is not even continuous. Still, it has some usual properties, like $1/\det w=\det 1/w$ and $\det wv=\det w \det v$.

Below is a table of some divergencies with their finite parts and determinants.

An interesting property is that the constant $e^{-\gamma}$ often appears in the expressions for these determinants.

Given that the regular part (which is analog of trace) is defined as
$$\operatorname{reg}(\omega_-+x)^a= B_a(x)=-a\zeta(1-a,x)$$
I see some similarity with functional determinant that also includes a zeta function.

I initially was going to name this thing "modulus" but later decided to call it "determinant" because it does not obey the triangle inequality and does not have other qualities of a norm.

But later I also noticed the striking similarity to the [functional determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_determinant). In functional determinant we have:

$$
\zeta _{S}(a)=\operatorname {tr} \,S^{-a}\,
$$

$$
\det S=e^{-\zeta _{S}'(0)}\,,
$$

In my system we have:

$$
\operatorname{reg } (\omega_-+s)^{-a}=a\zeta(1+a,s)
$$

(by definition)

and this  (I specifically tested this in Mathematica):

$$
\det (\omega_-+s)=e^{p.v._{a\to0}\frac{d}{da}( a\zeta(1+a,s))}
$$

The power has a pole at $a=0$, so we find the principal value there.

This similarity looked like a coincidence to me.

I wonder, what intuitively can indicate such determinant of a divergent integral or series? Can it tell something about its properties?

$$\small
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \text{Delta form} & \text{In terms of } \tau, \omega_+,\omega_- & \text{Finite part} & \text{Integral or series form} & \text{Germ form} &\text{Determinant}\\
 \pi  \delta (0) & \tau  & 0 & \int_0^{\infty } \, dx;\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx & \underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}} x;\underset{x\to0^+}{\operatorname{germ}}\frac1x&\frac{e^{-\gamma}}4 \\
 \pi  \delta (0)-\frac{1}{2} & \omega _-;\tau-\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } 1; \int_{1/2}^\infty dx & \underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}} (x-1/2) &e^{-\gamma} \\
 \pi  \delta (0)+\frac{1}{2} & \omega _+;\tau+\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} &\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } 1; \int_{-1/2}^\infty dx & \underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}} (x+1/2) & e^{-\gamma}  \\
 2 \pi  \delta (i) & e^{\omega_+}-e^{\omega_-}-1 & 0 & \int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^x \, dx & \underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}} e^x &(1)\\
& \frac{\tau ^2}{2}+\frac{1}{24};\frac{\omega_+^3-\omega_-^3}6 & 0 & \int_0^{\infty} x \, dx;\int_0^\infty \frac2{x^3}dx & \underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}}\frac{x^2}2;\underset{x\to0^+}{\operatorname{germ}} \frac1{x^2}&(2)\\
 & \frac{\tau ^2}{2}-\frac{1}{24} & -\frac1{12} & \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } k & \underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}} \left(\frac{x^2}2-\frac1{12}\right)&(3) \\
 -\pi \delta''(0) &\frac {\tau^3}3 +\frac\tau{12};\frac{\omega_+^4-\omega_-^4}{12}& 0 & \int_0^\infty x^2dx;\int_0^\infty\frac6{x^4}dx&\underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}}\frac{x^3}3;\underset{x\to0^+}{\operatorname{germ}} \frac2{x^3}\\
\pi^2\delta(0)^2-\pi\delta(0)+1/4&\omega_-^2&\frac16&2 \int_0^{\infty } \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right) \, dx+\frac{1}{6}&\underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}}B_2(x)&e^{-2\gamma}\\
\pi^2\delta(0)^2+\pi\delta(0)+1/4&\omega_+^2&\frac16&2 \int_0^{\infty } \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right) \, dx+\frac{1}{6}&\underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}}B_2(x+1)&e^{-2\gamma}\\
\pi^2\delta(0)^2&\tau^2&-\frac1{12}&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty } |x| \, dx-\frac{1}{12}&\underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}}B_2(x+1/2)&\frac{e^{-2\gamma}}{16} \\
&\ln \omega_++\gamma&0&\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}x;\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1x -\gamma&\underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}}\ln x\\
 -3\pi\delta''(0)-\frac14 \pi\delta(0);\pi^3\delta(0)^3&\tau^3&0&\int_0^\infty \left(3x^2-\frac1{4}\right)dx&\underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}}B_3(x+1/2)&\frac{e^{-3\gamma}}{64} \\
\frac{2\pi\delta(i)+1}{e-1}&e^{\omega_-}&\frac1{e-1}&\frac1{e-1}+\frac1{e-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^x dx&\underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}} \frac{e^x+1}{e-1}&\frac1{\sqrt{e}}\\
\frac{2\pi\delta(i)+1}{1-e^{-1}}&e^{\omega_+}&\frac1{1-e^{-1}}&\frac1{1-e^{-1}}+\frac1{1-e^{-1}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^x dx&\underset{x\to\infty}{\operatorname{germ}} \frac{e^x+1}{1-e^{-1}}&\sqrt{e}\\
&(-1)^\tau&\frac\pi{2}&&&1\\
\end{array}
$$

Missing from the table above:

$(1)=e^{\psi _e(\ln (e-1))}$

$(2)=e^{\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)+\psi\left(\frac12-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)}$

$(3)=e^{\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)+\psi\left(\frac12-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)}$